# Randomly joining where multiple rows meet join criteria

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here is a very simplified version of my SQLite data:

```sql
CREATE Table Questionnaires
(
   questionnaire_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   seconds INTEGER NOT NULL,
   measure CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
   score INTEGER NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (questionnaire_id)
)

INSERT INTO Questionnaires (seconds, measure, score) VALUES (5, 'PHQ9', 10), (5, 'GAD7', 8), (20, 'PHQ9', 5)

CREATE Table Events
(
   event_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   seconds INTEGER NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (event_id)
)

INSERT INTO Events (seconds) VALUES (5), (5), (10), (15), (20)
```

I would like to join the two tables on `seconds`. My current attempt is not giving the result I want:

```sql
SELECT
    Events.event_id,
    Questionnaires.questionnaire_id,
    Questionnaires.seconds,
    Questionnaires.measure,
    Questionnaires.score
FROM Questionnaires
LEFT OUTER JOIN Events
ON Events.seconds = Questionnaires.seconds
```

There are two questionnaires at `seconds == 5` and two events at `seconds == 5` and so the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` gives me four resulting rows, i.e.

1. questionnaire 1 joined with event 1,
2. questionnaire 1 joined with event 2,
3. questionnaire 2 joined with event 1, and
4. questionnaire 2 joined with event 2.

But what I want is either

- questionnaire 1 joined with event 1 and questionnaire 2 joined with event 2, or
- questionnaire 1 joined with event 2 and questionnaire 2 joined with event 1.

I do not mind which of these I get.

I can see how to do this in a procedural language but I cannot see how to do it in SQL in a set-theoretic way.

Any ideas?

(N.B. In my real data-set duplicate matching events are rare, that is why I did not spot my stupid mistake.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` window function on both tables before joining:

```
select
    e.event_id,
    q.questionnaire_id,
    q.seconds,
    q.measure,
    q.score
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by seconds order by questionnaire_id) rn
  from Questionnaires
) q left join (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by seconds order by event_id) rn
  from Events
) e on e.seconds = q.seconds and e.rn = q.rn
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3WDVp8edfYTD1r4czov2zR/2).
Or without window functions:

```
SELECT
    e.event_id,
    q.questionnaire_id,
    q.seconds,
    q.measure,
    q.score
FROM Questionnaires q LEFT OUTER JOIN Events e
ON e.seconds = q.seconds
AND (select count(*) from Questionnaires where seconds = q.seconds and questionnaire_id < q.questionnaire_id) =
    (select count(*) from Events where seconds = e.seconds and event_id < e.event_id);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cLaVfqCY1EkC257jF5z4X6/3).
Results:

```
| event_id | questionnaire_id | seconds | measure | score |
| -------- | ---------------- | ------- | ------- | ----- |
| 1        | 1                | 5       | PHQ9    | 10    |
| 2        | 2                | 5       | GAD7    | 8     |
| 5        | 3                | 20      | PHQ9    | 5     |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your select in a subquery and choose one row using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT eq.event_id, eq.questionnaire_id, eq.seconds,
       eq.measure, eq.score,
FROM (SELECT e.event_id, q.questionnaire_id, q.seconds,
             q.measure, q.score,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.event_id ORDER BY e.event_id) as seqnum
      FROM Questionnaires q LEFT JOIN
           Events e
           ON e.seconds = q.seconds
     ) eq
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

If there are lots of duplicates, this may not have optimal performance.  But for just a handful in each table, it should be fine.

Comment: This drops q2. The result I get running your query is e1 with q1, and e2 with q1, and no match returned for q2. Interesting but not what I was after.